NpgsqlDataAdapter.FillSchema Getting Table with incorrect AllowDBNull values
I am using NpgsqlDataAdapter to fill a table, so that I can see all of my table columns and properties in my API. One property that I am looking at is AllowDBNull. If my postgres table a column with the NOT NULL constraint, AllowDBNull should be false. However, besides my primary key column, all columns are coming back with AllowDBNull as true.
This was not an issue before we upgraded .NET6 -> .NET8 and NpgSql from 6.0.12 to 8.0.4
We are currently only experiencing this problem with tables that are created after the update. We have not updated our PostgreSQL version since before we had these issues. We are on PostgreSQL 15.2
The following is a code snippet that produces this issue.
using Npgsql;
using System.Data;

var table = new DataTable();

using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(DBConnectionConfig.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = "SELECT * FROM integration.file_import2",
            CommandTimeout = 30
        })
    {
        command.Connection = connection;

        var adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
    }
}

The following is the DDL for the table used in the example. The issue is happening with any new table with all different datatypes.

CREATE TABLE integration.file_import2 (
    file_import2_id uuid NOT NULL,
    imported_by_id uuid NOT NULL,
    imported_on timestamp NOT NULL,
    import_type varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    state varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(255) NULL,
    file_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    file_hash varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

